# Python websockets: How to reuse single websocket for multiple routes/paths

Tags: python, websocket

How can I use a single websocket (on client side) to send messages on multiple routes/paths. Suppose I have server running on ws://localhost:5005 and a websocket opened using:

```
async with websockets.client.connect("ws://localhost:5005") as websocket:
```

Suppose, I want to send messages at `ws://localhost:5005/init` and `ws://localhost:5005/echo` using the same websocket. However, I am unable to find the provision of some path/route parameter in `send()` method os websocket. Is there some way to do it?

Comment: Does it have to be the same Websocket? If so, why is that? I would suggest building new connections for each path unless you have a reason to not want to open two seperate sockets to communicate.

Comment: its not possible with python websockets, as the path (URI) is accepted only in the `connect()` method

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The path would hint to the server what type of service you are connecting to. Example: "chat" or "files" or whatever. But on the client end, you would need a separate socket for each service.

Comment: All, I have AsyncAPI specification with arount 30 APIs and want to consume a single websocket for all routes (one route per API). So, is there some way out?